# For-each cycle inside for-each cycle

Tags: xml, xslt, foreach, xsl-fo

Hi I would need help from XSL-FO Schema. I use three for-each cycles nested within each other. But for every "DVD" that lists all the "Movie" and everyone "Movie" that lists all the "Characters". I need to advice how do I enter a condition to display only movies that are on that DVD and characters who are in the movie.

The xml file:

```
<databaza>
<dvd>
    <id>01</id>
    <typ_DVD>DVD-R</typ_DVD>
    <nazov_DVD>Filmy-1994</nazov_DVD>
    <datum_vytvorenia>20.3.2015</datum_vytvorenia>
    <volne_miesto>249 MB</volne_miesto>
    <prepisovatelne>NIE</prepisovatelne>
    <pocet_filmov>2</pocet_filmov>
    <movie>
        <film_id>1</film_id>
        <nazov_filmu>Vykoupení z věznice Shawshank </nazov_filmu>
        <popis>Strhující příběh o přátelství, naději a moudrosti s velmi výraznými hereckými i charakterovými osobnostmi.</popis>
        <dlzka>142 min</dlzka>
        <jazyk>CZK</jazyk>
        <titulky>NIE</titulky>
        <jazyk_titulky>Bez tituliek</jazyk_titulky>
        <pocet_postav>2</pocet_postav>
        <character>
            <postava_id>1</postava_id>
            <nazov_postava>Andy Dufresne</nazov_postava>
            <hlavna_postava>ANO</hlavna_postava>
            <hral>Tim Robbins</hral>            
        </character>
        <character>
            <postava_id>1</postava_id>
            <nazov_postava>Rede</nazov_postava>
            <hlavna_postava>ANO</hlavna_postava>
            <hral>Morgan Freeman</hral>         
        </character>
    </movie>
    <movie>
        <film_id>2</film_id>
        <nazov_filmu>Forrest Gump</nazov_filmu>
        <popis>Forrest Gump, typický obyčejný muž, 
            který od dětství dělal, co se mu řeklo.</popis>
        <dlzka>142 min</dlzka>
        <jazyk>CZK</jazyk>
        <titulky>NIE</titulky>
        <jazyk_titulky>Bez tituliek</jazyk_titulky>
        <pocet_postav>4</pocet_postav>
        <character>
            <postava_id>2</postava_id>
            <nazov_postava>Forrest Gump</nazov_postava>
            <hlavna_postava>ANO</hlavna_postava>
            <hral>Tom Hanks</hral>          
        </character>
        <character>
            <postava_id>2</postava_id>
            <nazov_postava>Jenny Curran</nazov_postava>
            <hlavna_postava>ANO</hlavna_postava>
            <hral>Robin Wright</hral>           
        </character>
        <character>
            <postava_id>2</postava_id>
            <nazov_postava>Bubba</nazov_postava>
            <hlavna_postava>ANO</hlavna_postava>
            <hral>Mykelti Williamson</hral>         
        </character>
        <character>
            <postava_id>2</postava_id>
            <nazov_postava>Dan Taylor</nazov_postava>
            <hlavna_postava>ANO</hlavna_postava>
            <hral>Gary Sinise</hral>            
        </character>
    </movie>
</dvd>

<dvd>
    <id>02</id>
    <typ_DVD>DVD-RW</typ_DVD>
    <nazov_DVD>Filmy-1999</nazov_DVD>
    <datum_vytvorenia>12.8.2015</datum_vytvorenia>
    <volne_miesto>24 MB</volne_miesto>
    <prepisovatelne>ANO</prepisovatelne>
    <pocet_filmov>3</pocet_filmov>
    <movie>
        <film_id>3</film_id>
        <nazov_filmu>Zelená míle</nazov_filmu>
        <popis>Paul pracuje jako dozorce ve vězení pro těžké zločince, 
            kteří jsou odsud posíláni na smrt.</popis>
        <dlzka>188 min</dlzka>
        <jazyk>ENG</jazyk>
        <titulky>ÁNO</titulky>
        <jazyk_titulky>CZK</jazyk_titulky>
        <pocet_postav>3</pocet_postav>
        <character>
            <postava_id>3</postava_id>
            <nazov_postava>Paul Edgecomb</nazov_postava>
            <hlavna_postava>ANO</hlavna_postava>
            <hral>Tom Hanks</hral>          
        </character>
        <character>
            <postava_id>3</postava_id>
            <nazov_postava>John Coffey</nazov_postava>
            <hlavna_postava>ANO</hlavna_postava>
            <hral>Michael Clarke Duncan</hral>          
        </character>
        <character>
            <postava_id>3</postava_id>
            <nazov_postava>Brutus „Brutal“ Howell</nazov_postava>
            <hlavna_postava>NIE</hlavna_postava>
            <hral>David Morse</hral>            
        </character>
    </movie>

    <movie>
        <film_id>4</film_id>
        <nazov_filmu>Matrix</nazov_filmu>
        <popis>Film popisuje svět v Matrixu, rozsáhlém počítačovém systému, 
            na který jsou připojeni lidé žijící v něm svůj virtuální život.</popis>
        <dlzka>131 min</dlzka>
        <jazyk>ENG</jazyk>
        <titulky>ÁNO</titulky>
        <jazyk_titulky>CZK</jazyk_titulky>
        <pocet_postav>3</pocet_postav>
        <character>
            <postava_id>4</postava_id>
            <nazov_postava>Neo</nazov_postava>
            <hlavna_postava>ANO</hlavna_postava>
            <hral>Keanu Reeves</hral>           
        </character>
        <character>
            <postava_id>4</postava_id>
            <nazov_postava>Morpheus</nazov_postava>
            <hlavna_postava>ANO</hlavna_postava>
            <hral>Laurence Fishburne</hral>         
        </character>
        <character>
            <postava_id>4</postava_id>
            <nazov_postava>Trinity</nazov_postava>
            <hlavna_postava>NIE</hlavna_postava>
            <hral>Carrie-Anne Moss</hral>           
        </character>
    </movie>

    <movie>
        <film_id>5</film_id>
        <nazov_filmu>Pelíšky</nazov_filmu>
        <popis>Príjemný film zaľudnený osobitými postavami, 
            s humorom a nadsázkou o rodinách, rodičoch, deťoch, 
            rodinných trapasoch, bolestiach a bremenách, ale aj o dobe, 
            v ktorej sa neroztápali len umelohmotné lyžičky v káve...</popis>
        <dlzka>115 min</dlzka>
        <jazyk>CZK</jazyk>
        <titulky>NIE</titulky>
        <jazyk_titulky>Bez tituliek</jazyk_titulky>
        <pocet_postav>3</pocet_postav>
        <character>
            <postava_id>5</postava_id>
            <nazov_postava>Šebek</nazov_postava>
            <hlavna_postava>ANO</hlavna_postava>
            <hral>Miroslav Donutil</hral>           
        </character>
        <character>
            <postava_id>5</postava_id>
            <nazov_postava>Michal Šebek</nazov_postava>
            <hlavna_postava>ANO</hlavna_postava>
            <hral>Michal Beran</hral>           
        </character>
        <character>
            <postava_id>5</postava_id>
            <nazov_postava>Babička Šebková</nazov_postava>
            <hlavna_postava>NIE</hlavna_postava>
            <hral>Stella Zázvorková</hral>          
        </character>
    </movie>
</dvd>

<dvd>
    <id>03</id>
    <typ_DVD>DVD-R</typ_DVD>
    <nazov_DVD>Rozprávky</nazov_DVD>
    <datum_vytvorenia>21.2.2015</datum_vytvorenia>
    <volne_miesto>322 MB</volne_miesto>
    <prepisovatelne>NIE</prepisovatelne>
    <pocet_filmov>2</pocet_filmov>
    <movie>
        <film_id>6</film_id>
        <nazov_filmu>Sněhurka a sedm trpaslíků</nazov_filmu>
        <popis>Příběh, ve kterém se mísí pohádkové kouzlo, 
            dechberoucí napětí a neobyčejná odvaha, začíná 
            jak jinak u kouzelného zrcadla.</popis>
        <dlzka>83 min</dlzka>
        <jazyk>CZK</jazyk>
        <titulky>NIE</titulky>
        <jazyk_titulky>Bez tituliek</jazyk_titulky>
        <pocet_postav>3</pocet_postav>
        <character>
            <postava_id>6</postava_id>
            <nazov_postava>Sněhurka</nazov_postava>
            <hlavna_postava>ANO</hlavna_postava>
            <hral>Kreslená postava</hral>           
        </character>
        <character>
            <postava_id>6</postava_id>
            <nazov_postava>Princ</nazov_postava>
            <hlavna_postava>ANO</hlavna_postava>
            <hral>Kreslená postava</hral>           
        </character>
        <character>
            <postava_id>6</postava_id>
            <nazov_postava>Královna</nazov_postava>
            <hlavna_postava>ANO</hlavna_postava>
            <hral>Kreslená postava</hral>           
        </character>
    </movie>
    <movie>
        <film_id>7</film_id>
        <nazov_filmu>Shrek </nazov_filmu>
        <popis>Shrek, zelený obr s tykadly mimozemšťanů, 
            žije sice docela sám, ale šťastně ve svém domku 
            na samotě u lesa až do chvíle, kdy je doslova 
            přepaden nekonečným zástupem známých i méně známých 
            pohádkových postaviček.</popis>
        <dlzka>90 min</dlzka>
        <jazyk>CZK</jazyk>
        <titulky>NIE</titulky>
        <jazyk_titulky>Bez tituliek</jazyk_titulky>
        <pocet_postav>4</pocet_postav>
        <character>
            <postava_id>7</postava_id>
            <nazov_postava>Shrek</nazov_postava>
            <hlavna_postava>ANO</hlavna_postava>
            <hral>Kreslená postava</hral>           
        </character>
        <character>
            <postava_id>7</postava_id>
            <nazov_postava>Princezna Fiona</nazov_postava>
            <hlavna_postava>ANO</hlavna_postava>
            <hral>Kreslená postava</hral>           
        </character>
        <character>
            <postava_id>7</postava_id>
            <nazov_postava>Oslík</nazov_postava>
            <hlavna_postava>ANO</hlavna_postava>
            <hral>Kreslená postava</hral>           
        </character>
        <character>
            <postava_id>7</postava_id>
            <nazov_postava>Kocour v botách</nazov_postava>
            <hlavna_postava>ANO</hlavna_postava>
            <hral>Kreslená postava</hral>           
        </character>
    </movie>
</dvd>
</databaza>
```

And now my xsl-fo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <fo:root>
        <fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:simple-page-master master-name="my-page" page-height="297mm" page-width="210mm"
                margin="1in">
                <fo:region-body margin-bottom="15mm" margin-top="15mm"/>
                <fo:region-after extent="5mm"/>
            </fo:simple-page-master>
        </fo:layout-master-set>

        <fo:page-sequence master-reference="my-page">

            <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-after">
                <fo:block text-align="center">
                    <xsl:text>Page </xsl:text>
                    <fo:page-number/>
                    <xsl:text> from </xsl:text>
                    <fo:page-number-citation ref-id="last_page"/>
                </fo:block>
            </fo:static-content>
            <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body" font-family="Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif"
                font-size="12pt">

                <xsl:apply-templates select="databaza"/>
            </fo:flow>
        </fo:page-sequence>
    </fo:root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:attribute-set name="bunka.datum">
    <xsl:attribute name="padding">2pt</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="text-align">center</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="border-style">solid</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="border-width">1pt</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:attribute-set>

<xsl:template match="databaza">
        <fo:table width="100%" border-width="1pt" border-after-width="0pt"
            border-collapse="collapse">
            <fo:table-column column-width="50%"/>
            <fo:table-column column-width="50%"/>
            <fo:table-body>
                <fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-cell padding="4pt" font-size="150%" font-weight="bold"
                        text-align="center" number-columns-spanned="2">
                        <fo:block>Osobné údaje:</fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>
                <fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-cell padding="4pt" border-style="solid" border-width="1pt">
                        <fo:block>Vlastník:</fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell padding="4pt" border-style="solid" border-width="1pt">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="vlastnik"/>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>
                <fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-cell padding="4pt" border-style="solid" border-width="1pt">
                        <fo:block>Adresa:</fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell padding="4pt" border-style="solid" border-width="1pt">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="adresa"/>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>
                <fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-cell padding="4pt" border-style="solid" border-width="1pt">
                        <fo:block>Telefónne číslo:</fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell padding="4pt" border-style="solid" border-width="1pt">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="telefon"/>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>
                <fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-cell number-columns-spanned="2">
                        <fo:block text-align-last="justify" space-after="0pt"
                            keep-with-next="always" clear="both" color="red">
                            <fo:leader leader-pattern="rule"/>
                        </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>
            </fo:table-body>
        </fo:table>

        <fo:block>
            <fo:leader/>
        </fo:block>
        <fo:block font-size="150%" font-weight="bold" text-align="center">Zoznam DVD:</fo:block>
        <fo:block>
            <fo:leader/>
        </fo:block>

        <xsl:for-each-group select="/databaza/dvd" group-by="id">
            <fo:block keep-together.within-column="always">
                <fo:table width="100%" border-width="1pt" border-after-width="0pt"
                    border-collapse="collapse">
                    <fo:table-column column-width="50%"/>
                    <fo:table-column column-width="50%"/>
                    <fo:table-body>
                        <fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-cell padding="4pt" font-size="150%" font-weight="bold"
                                text-align="center" number-columns-spanned="2">
                                <fo:block>DVD:</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                        </fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-cell padding="4pt" border-style="solid" border-width="1pt">
                                <fo:block>Typ DVD:</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell padding="4pt" border-style="solid" border-width="1pt">
                                <xsl:apply-templates select="typ_DVD"/>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                        </fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-cell padding="4pt" border-style="solid" border-width="1pt">
                                <fo:block>Dátum vytvorenia:</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell padding="4pt" border-style="solid" border-width="1pt">
                                <xsl:apply-templates select="datum_vytvorenia"/>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                        </fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-cell padding="4pt" border-style="solid" border-width="1pt">
                                <fo:block>Voľné miesto:</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell padding="4pt" border-style="solid" border-width="1pt">
                                <xsl:apply-templates select="volne_miesto"/>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                        </fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-cell padding="4pt" border-style="solid" border-width="1pt">
                                <fo:block>Prepisovateľné:</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell padding="4pt" border-style="solid" border-width="1pt">
                                <xsl:apply-templates select="prepisovatelne"/>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                        </fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-cell padding="4pt" border-style="solid" border-width="1pt">
                                <fo:block>Počet filmov:</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell padding="4pt" border-style="solid" border-width="1pt">
                                <xsl:apply-templates select="pocet_filmov"/>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                        </fo:table-row>
                    </fo:table-body>
                </fo:table>
            </fo:block>

            <xsl:for-each select="/databaza/dvd/movie">
                <fo:block keep-together.within-column="always">
                    <fo:table width="100%" border-width="1pt" border-after-width="0pt"
                        border-collapse="collapse">
                        <fo:table-column column-width="50%"/>
                        <fo:table-column column-width="50%"/>
                        <fo:table-body>
                            <fo:table-row>
                                <fo:table-cell padding="4pt" font-size="150%" font-weight="bold"
                                    text-align="center" number-columns-spanned="2">
                                    <fo:block>Movie:</fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                            </fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-row>
                                <fo:table-cell padding="4pt" border-style="solid"
                                    border-width="1pt">
                                    <fo:block>Názov filmu:</fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell padding="4pt" border-style="solid"
                                    border-width="1pt">
                                    <xsl:apply-templates select="nazov_filmu"/>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                            </fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-row>
                                <fo:table-cell padding="4pt" border-style="solid"
                                    border-width="1pt">
                                    <fo:block>Popis:</fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell padding="4pt" border-style="solid"
                                    border-width="1pt">
                                    <xsl:apply-templates select="popis"/>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                            </fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-row>
                                <fo:table-cell padding="4pt" border-style="solid"
                                    border-width="1pt">
                                    <fo:block>Dĺžka:</fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell padding="4pt" border-style="solid"
                                    border-width="1pt">
                                    <xsl:apply-templates select="dlzka"/>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                            </fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-row>
                                <fo:table-cell padding="4pt" border-style="solid"
                                    border-width="1pt">
                                    <fo:block>Jazyk:</fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell padding="4pt" border-style="solid"
                                    border-width="1pt">
                                    <xsl:apply-templates select="jazyk"/>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                            </fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-row>
                                <fo:table-cell padding="4pt" border-style="solid"
                                    border-width="1pt">
                                    <fo:block>Titulky:</fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell padding="4pt" border-style="solid"
                                    border-width="1pt">
                                    <xsl:apply-templates select="titulky"/>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                            </fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-row>
                                <fo:table-cell padding="4pt" border-style="solid"
                                    border-width="1pt">
                                    <fo:block>Jazyk Tituliek:</fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell padding="4pt" border-style="solid"
                                    border-width="1pt">
                                    <xsl:apply-templates select="jazyk_titulky"/>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                            </fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-row>
                                <fo:table-cell padding="4pt" border-style="solid"
                                    border-width="1pt">
                                    <fo:block>Počet postáv:</fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell padding="4pt" border-style="solid"
                                    border-width="1pt">
                                    <xsl:apply-templates select="pocet_postav"/>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                            </fo:table-row>
                        </fo:table-body>
                    </fo:table>
                </fo:block>
                <xsl:for-each select="/databaza/dvd/movie/character">
                    <fo:block keep-together.within-column="always">

                        <fo:table width="100%" border-width="1pt" border-after-width="0pt"
                            border-collapse="collapse">
                            <fo:table-column column-width="50%"/>
                            <fo:table-column column-width="50%"/>
                            <fo:table-body>
                                <fo:table-row>
                                    <fo:table-cell padding="4pt" font-size="150%"
                                        font-weight="bold" text-align="center"
                                        number-columns-spanned="2">
                                        <fo:block>Character:</fo:block>
                                    </fo:table-cell>
                                </fo:table-row>
                                <fo:table-row>
                                    <fo:table-cell padding="4pt" border-style="solid"
                                        border-width="1pt">
                                        <fo:block>Názov postavy:</fo:block>
                                    </fo:table-cell>
                                    <fo:table-cell padding="4pt" border-style="solid"
                                        border-width="1pt">
                                        <xsl:apply-templates select="nazov_postava"/>
                                    </fo:table-cell>
                                </fo:table-row>
                                <fo:table-row>
                                    <fo:table-cell padding="4pt" border-style="solid"
                                        border-width="1pt">
                                        <fo:block>Hlavná postava:</fo:block>
                                    </fo:table-cell>
                                    <fo:table-cell padding="4pt" border-style="solid"
                                        border-width="1pt">
                                        <xsl:apply-templates select="hlavna_postava"/>
                                    </fo:table-cell>
                                </fo:table-row>
                                <fo:table-row>
                                    <fo:table-cell padding="4pt" border-style="solid"
                                        border-width="1pt">
                                        <fo:block>Hral:</fo:block>
                                    </fo:table-cell>
                                    <fo:table-cell padding="4pt" border-style="solid"
                                        border-width="1pt">
                                        <xsl:apply-templates select="hral"/>
                                    </fo:table-cell>
                                </fo:table-row>
                                <fo:table-row>
                                    <fo:table-cell number-columns-spanned="2">
                                        <fo:block text-align-last="justify" space-after="0pt"
                                            keep-with-next="always" clear="both" color="red">
                                            <fo:leader leader-pattern="rule"/>
                                        </fo:block>
                                    </fo:table-cell>
                                </fo:table-row>
                            </fo:table-body>
                        </fo:table>
                    </fo:block>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each-group>

    <fo:block id="last_page"/>
</xsl:template>



<xsl:template match="vlastnik">
    <fo:block>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="adresa">
    <fo:block>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="telefon">
    <fo:block>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="typ_DVD">
    <fo:block>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="nazov_DVD">
    <fo:block>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="datum_vytvorenia">
    <fo:block>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="volne_miesto">
    <fo:block>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="prepisovatelne">
    <fo:block>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="pocet_filmov">
    <fo:block>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="film_id">
    <fo:block>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="nazov_filmu">
    <fo:block>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="popis">
    <fo:block>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="dlzka">
    <fo:block>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="jazyk">
    <fo:block>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="titulky">
    <fo:block>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="jazyk_titulky">
    <fo:block>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="pocet_postav">
    <fo:block>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="postava_id">
    <fo:block>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="nazov_postava">
    <fo:block>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="hlavna_postava">
    <fo:block>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="hral">
    <fo:block>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I change the name of the main parts, others are written in a czech language.
Can you help me with this problem ?

Answer (score 2):

As the elements are nested, you can simply replace `<xsl:for-each select="/databaza/dvd/movie">` with `<xsl:for-each select="movie">` or perhaps, as you use grouping, you want `<xsl:for-each select="current-group()/movie">` and then inside `<xsl:for-each select="character">`.